# Django Process Form data in views.py on submit

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I Want to process my form data and view and update my mongo DB if name not present else if name present update the DB.
Before that, I want to make sure if the entire subject is proper.. using some regex.

But when I add name and subject in below form code nothing is happening.
How do I get the form data in view and do the proper check?
And where should I do the input validation in views or form.html ??

if entered data is not proper format throw error? how can I do this?

form_template.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-area">
        <form id="add-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'myapp:add_data' %}" role="form">
        <br style="clear:both">
                    <h4 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;"> New Data</h3>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sub_list" name="sub_list" placeholder="Sub List comma separated" required>
                                        </div>
                                         <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

myapp/url.py

```
url(r'^new_data$', views.add_data, name='add_data'),
```

And below is my view function

```
def add_data(request):
    print "Herfe"
    if request.POST:
        print "coming here"
        I want validate user entered input is proper
        messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')
        return render(request, '/index.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `request.POST.get(<name>)` to get the data from the template and then preprocess it.

So in your case it simply becomes

```
def add_data(request):
    print "Herfe"
    if request.POST:
        print "coming here"
        data = request.POST.get('name')
        # now validate to your heart's content
        messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')
        return render(request, '/index.html')
```

On a side note I think you are missing out the benefits of `forms` in django. If you use the [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) API properly you can easily pass values and validate them with inbuilt methods. In that case it would become

```
form = YourForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    your_variable = form.cleaned_data['name'] # validates for malicious data automatically
    # Now you can do further validations accordingly.
```

Comment: but when i click on submit it is supposed to come in add_data() and print coming here.. But its not printing .. so i'm still confused if i have missed anything

Comment: yeah if i want to use forms what changes am i supposed to do ??

Comment: Any simple django form process using form API example link ?? i can use

Comment: Yea there are lot of tutorials by using Forms API. The official django tutorial on Forms would be enough to give a basic understanding on what it's capable of. I've already linked that in my answer :)